# Grammatical error (inelegance at the very least) in a close reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

One of the canned messages for closing a question reads

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. **As it's currently written**, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

There is no subject to which the *it's* refers. As *what* is currently written? While it's true that there is not much room for misunderstanding, it is inelegant and, strictly speaking, ungrammatical. Could we please change that to something like

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what **your post** is asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

I realize this is not that important but it bugs the grammar Nazi in me.

Comment: My grammar may not be the best, but it sounds like the 'it' is referring to the 'specific problem' from the first sentence.

Comment: @minerz029 Ah, but can a problem be _written_? It can be _described_ or _explained_ or even _written down_ but _written_ alone? It is the question that describes the problem that is written, not the problem itself.